# How to display classpath used for run task?

Tags: sbt

How can the classpath used for `run` task be displayed under SBT 0.13?

I have found some info here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/0rhVRPnjyZU/DOYAd14gh1wJ:

> I was dumping my classpaths as a way to troubleshoot my build recently and maybe this task can help you too:
>
> ```
> lazy val printClasspath = task {
>   this.runClasspath.getPaths.foreach(println);
>   None
> }
> ```
>
> runClasspath is a PathFinder [1] instance and you can interrogate it even further. I guess building a ':'-separated list of those paths will be easy.

I don't understand where and how I should use this tip. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line `lazy val printClasspath ...` in your build.sbt file.

Then at the command line run:

`sbt printClasspath`

Comment: `lazy val printClasspath ...` is not a working example

Comment: @EricKolotyluk That line is a quote from the question. I was explaining where it should be put.

Comment: So what you meant to say was "At the line" instead of "Add the line"?

Comment: No. The OP saw some lines of code in some post that add a task to the build, and didn't know where to put them. I just said "put them in build.sbt", which answers that question. Granted, there is a way to see the classpath without it, as was mentioned by Seth Tisue.

Answer (score 64):

If I type this in the sbt shell:

```
inspect run
```

I see, among other output:

```
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  runtime:fullClasspath
```

So then if I type:

```
show runtime:fullClasspath
```

I get output like:

```
 List(
   Attributed(/Users/tisue/Dropbox/repos/euler/target/scala-2.10/classes),
   Attributed(/Users/tisue/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar))
```

Which is probably what you were looking for?

You can also get it in a colon-separated form suitable for use with `java -classpath` on the command line:

```
export runtime:fullClasspath
```

which prints e.g.:

```
/Users/tisue/Dropbox/repos/euler/target/scala-2.10/classes:/Users/tisue/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar
```

Comment: Doh, you beat me to it. I do hope however that you don't mind my answer that goes a bit further and shows a sample task to print out the classpath for the runtime configuration. It's always good to see my thinking was correct. Thanks!

Comment: And for SBT 0.12.X it seems to be just: `show runtime:full-classpath`

Comment: This is the best answer for the OP. If you want to find the run task classpath you don't need to write a task to do it.

Comment: `sbt "export runtime:fullClasspath"` outputs the classpath as a colon-separated list perfect if you want to use it for invoking Scala.

Comment: @nedim your *comment"+* is actaully the best *answer* here. suggest making it one.

Comment: @javadba I've incorporated nedim's comment into my answer.

Answer (score 15):

**tl;dr** Use `last run` or write a custom task.

### last run

With `last run` you should be presented with the entire classpath:

```
[info] Running main.Main
[debug] Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
[debug]   Classpath:
[debug]     /Users/jacek/work/ingrifo/dictionary-spray/target/scala-2.11/classes
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.4.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-can_2.11/bundles/spray-can_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-io_2.11/bundles/spray-io_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-util_2.11/bundles/spray-util_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-http_2.11/bundles/spray-http_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.11/bundles/parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.6.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/bundles/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-routing_2.11/bundles/spray-routing_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-httpx_2.11/bundles/spray-httpx_2.11-1.3.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/jars/mimepull-1.9.4.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.11/jars/shapeless_2.11-1.2.4.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.11/bundles/spray-json_2.11-1.3.1.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.6.jar
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.2.1.jar
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main-0 to terminate.
[debug]     Thread run-main-0 exited.
[debug] Waiting for thread default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 to terminate.
```

### Custom task to dump CLASSPATH

If you need to see what the `run` task depends on, use `inspect`.

```
[fullclasspath]> inspect run
[info] Input task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Runs a main class, passing along arguments provided on the command line.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/fullClasspath/}fullclasspath/compile:run
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:704
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:run::streams
[info]  runtime:fullClasspath
[info]  compile:run::runner
[info]  compile:run::mainClass
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:run
[info]  *:run
[info]  {.}/compile:run
[info]  {.}/*:run
[info]  */compile:run
[info]  */*:run
[info] Related:
[info]  test:run
```

In `Dependencies` there's the `runtime:fullClasspath` setting which means that `run` depends on its value.

According to SBT `help`, `fullClasspath` is...

```
[fullclasspath]> help fullClasspath
The exported classpath, consisting of build products and unmanaged and managed, internal and external dependencies.
```

You simply need to parse the value of the `runtime:fullClasspath` setting.

```
[fullclasspath]> show runtime:fullClasspath
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/fullClasspath/}fullclasspath...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] List(Attributed(/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/fullClasspath/target/scala-2.10/classes), Attributed(/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 13, 2014 1:27:38 AM
```

To have a more parsable output, use the following task that reads `fullClasspath` as defined for the `runtime` scope (`Runtime` in Scala/SBT code):

```
lazy val printClasspath = taskKey[Unit]("Dump classpath")

printClasspath := {
  (fullClasspath in Runtime value) foreach {
    e => println(e.data)
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the `Runtime` configuration is hardcoded and think an input task to accept a configuration would make it so much better.

Answer (score 12):

or directly from the bash , dash , sh or whatever shell:

```
 sbt 'inspect run' 'show runtime:fullClasspath'
```

and

```
 sbt "inspect run" "show runtime:fullClasspath"
```

for Windows command line.

Comment: You can always use double quotes in bash too.

Comment: Yes, yet a good general bash interpolation/substitution practice could be "do not interpolate/substitute unless you need to ". This was the reason I used single quotes for bash, which in this context YES is obsolete ...