# How SBT test task manages class path and how to correctly start a Java process from SBT test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, process, jvm, sbt

In one of my Scala tests, using `ProcessBuilder`, I fire up 3 Apache Spark streaming applications in separate JVMs. (Two or more Spark streaming applications can not co-exist in the same JVM.) One Spark application processes data and ingests into Apache Kafka, which the other ones read. Moreover the test involves writing into a NoSQL database.

While using `ProcessBuilder`, the Spark application's class path is set using:

`val classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

Running the test in IntelliJ works as expected, but on a CI system, the test is invoked by SBT's test task. The `java.class.path` in the latter case, will be solely the `sbt.jar`, so the child JVM exits with `NoClassFoundException`, again, as expected. :-)

I'm looking for a way to "span" JVMs from SBT tests using the same class path that the tests are actually using. For example if the test is invoked in project `core`, the class path of project `core` should be supplied to the child JVM, where the Spark application starts. Unfortunately I have got no idea how to retrieve the correct class path in SBT tasks - which then could be supplied to child JVMs.

Comment: Do you have `fork in Test := true`?

Comment: Thanks for asking! No, fork is disabled. I found out that if fork is enabled in `Test`, resources will not be put to the class path, and a lot of tests depend on resources even from a parent project. Parallel execution is also disabled (due to using Spark applications in single JVM).

Comment: See if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698205/how-to-display-classpath-used-for-run-task

Comment: I see that question considers the retrieval of classpath using an `sbt` task. Can that be used in a test suite or the classpath information to be propagated into the test suite as a value?

Answer (score 3):

[`Tests.Setup`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Setup+and+Cleanup) can be used to access the classpath within SBT:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup { classLoader =>
   // give Spark classpath via classLoader
}
```

For example, on my machine `Tests.Setup(classLoader => println(classLoader))` gives

```
> test
ClasspathFilter(
  parent = URLClassLoader with NativeCopyLoader with RawResources(
  urls = List(/home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/test-classes, /home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/classes, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar),
  parent = DualLoader(a = java.net.URLClassLoader@3fcb37f1, b = java.net.URLClassLoader@271053e1),
  resourceMap = Set(app.class.path, boot.class.path),
  nativeTemp = /tmp/sbt_741bc913/sbt_c770779a
)
  root = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@33909752
  cp = Set(/home/mario/.ivy2/cache/jline/jline/jars/jline-2.14.5.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar, /home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/classes, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.7/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/test-interface-1.0.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/test-classes, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.4.jar)
)
```

where we see that

```
.../target/scala-2.12/test-classes
.../target/scala-2.12/classes
```

are present.

On the other hand, to retrieve the classpath from within the test itself:

```
val classLoader = this.getClass.getClassLoader
// give Spark classpath via classLoader
```

For example, on my machine, `println(classLoader)` given in the following test

```
class CubeCalculatorTest extends FunSuite {
  test("CubeCalculator.cube") {
    val classLoader = this.getClass.getClassLoader
    println(classLoader)
    assert(CubeCalculator.cube(3) === 27)
  }
}
```

prints

```
URLClassLoader with NativeCopyLoader with RawResources(
  urls = List(/home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/test-classes, /home/mario/sandbox/sbt/so-classpath/target/scala-2.12/classes, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.4.jar, /home/mario/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar),
  parent = DualLoader(a = java.net.URLClassLoader@6307eb76, b = java.net.URLClassLoader@271053e1),
  resourceMap = Set(app.class.path, boot.class.path),
  nativeTemp = /tmp/sbt_fa64d1a1/sbt_66bd50e2
)
```

where again we can see

```
.../target/scala-2.12/test-classes
.../target/scala-2.12/classes
```

are present.

To actually pass the classpath to [`ProcessBuilder`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html) within a test:

```
import java.net.URLClassLoader
import sys.process._

class CubeCalculatorTest extends FunSuite {
  test("CubeCalculator.cube") {
    val classLoader = this.getClass.getClassLoader
    val classpath = classLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs.map(_.getFile).mkString(":")
    s"java -classpath $classpath MyExternalApp".!
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, how may I use the `classLoader` variable in my `FunSuite` Scala test and give it to the `ProcessBuilder`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full `classpath`, to be used in the `ProcessBuilder`'s JVM, from your `sbt` tests, with:

```scala
Thread
  .currentThread
  .getContextClassLoader
  .getParent
  .asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader]
  .getURLs
  .map(_.getFile)
  .mkString(System.getProperty("path.separator"))
```