# Does `sbt run`on a project install scala compiler, interpreter and dependencies locally to the project?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

If I am correct, Scala is usually installed by sbt for each of your Scala projects rather than being
installed system-wide.

I created a simple example:

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

When I run `sbt run` on a Scala sbt project, I saw several local directories created, for example `target`.

What does `sbt run` install and where?

- Does it install scala compiler and scala and bytecode interpreters somewhere?
- Does it install dependencies somewhere? When the sbt project depends on very large dependencies, e.g. Spark, does `sbt run` install them locally to the project? (consider when there are many Spark applications, and installing Spark lcally to each application doesn't seem to be a good idea.)

Thanks.

Comment: _"Does it install scala compiler & dependencies"_, yes but not exactly the `run` task. `run` depends on `compile` which depends on others like resolving dependencies, etc. _"somewhere"_ so for **SBT** the scala compiler, interpreter, library are just other dependencies of your project, so they are treated equally. You are right that installing the for every project seems wasteful but at the end is a valid idea if you want isolated environments _(that is what python virtual environments usually do AFAIK)_, but thankfully since **Java** has the concept of `CLASSPATH` all jars can be shared.

Comment: Depending on your **SBT** version the exact folder _(and actually the download implementation)_ change. But the behavior is similar, all dependencies are downloaded only once and stored on some cache folder, to be reused. SBT then configures the `CLASSPATH` of each project to only load the required dependencies. This means that you can even have _"installed"_ many versions of the same dependency. - Current versions of **SBT** uses **ivy2** for downloading the dependencies, stored on `~/.ivy2` - [more information](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Ivy+Home+Directory).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Since 1.3.0 sbt switched to Coursier.

Comment: @MarioGalic oh yeah and **Coursier** stored them in `~/.cache/coursier` thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does sbt run install them locally to the project?

sbt resloves dependencies using Coursier [since 1.3.0](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Automatic+Dependency+Management)

> sbt 1.3.0+ uses Coursier to implement dependency management. Until sbt
>   1.3.0, sbt has used Apache Ivy for ten years.

to a central repository on your local machine. We can show Coursier cache directory by executing

```
csrCacheDirectory
```

which on my machine gives

```
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1
```

Hence dependencies are **not** installed per-project within a directory local to the project. These dependencies are fetched remotely only once per version of the dependency the first time some project requires it, and then all other projects that depend on this same version fetch it from the local cache.

To [print](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738753/5205022) the complete classpath used by `sbt run` execute

```
show runtime:fullClasspath
```

which outputs something like

```
sbt:scala-runner-classpath> show runtime:fullClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/scala-runner-classpath/target/scala-2.13/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.1/scala-library-2.13.1.jar)
```